# Android: I click on the button to play the sound

Tags: android

I'm creating piano app but I got problem when i click on the button to play many times i can't hear sound when i click on the button again. After i click on the button many times all the sounds are not heard how to solve this problem?

```
public class Music_piano extends Activity {
Button btn_s_ddo,btn_s_re,btn_s_mi,btn_s_fa,btn_s_so,btn_s_la,btn_s_si,btn_ldo;
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
MediaPlayer mp1,mp2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_music_piano);
}
    public void btn_sound_ddo(View v){
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ddo);
      mp.start();
}
public void btn_sound_re(View v){
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.re);
      mp.start();
}
public void btn_sound_mi(View v){
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mi);
      mp.start();
}
public void btn_sound_fa(View v){
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fa);
      mp.start();
}
public void btn_sound_so(View v){
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sol);
      mp.start();
}
public void btn_sound_la(View v){
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.la);
      mp.start();
}
public void btn_sound_si(View v){
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.si);
      mp.start();
}
public void btn_sound_ldo(View v){
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ddo_last);
      mp.start();
}
}
```

Comment: You are better off with [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html).

Comment: i'm just learn in android so can you give a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code ? I have tried it, worked well for me.

```
 Button btnOne = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
 btnOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
         MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(TempActivity.this, R.raw.mysoundfile);
         mPlayer.start();
       }
   });
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

its better to create single instance of `MediaPlayer` and reuse it

```
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); // global variable


//write below code on buttons onclick method
            AssetFileDescriptor assetFile = context.getAssets().openFd(audioFile);
            mMediaPlayer.reset();
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetFile.getFileDescriptor(),
                    assetFile.getStartOffset(), assetFile.getLength());
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple SoundManager class with a demo activity. No comment whatsoever as I think its pretty easy to read. Refer to [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) for details.

`SoundManager` class

```
package com.makeez.sfx;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.SoundPool;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SoundManager {
    private final Map<Integer, Integer> sfxId = new HashMap<>();
    private SoundPool sfx;

    public SoundManager(int maxStreams, int streamType, int srcQuality) {
        sfx = new SoundPool(maxStreams, streamType, srcQuality);
    }

    public void load(Context context, int... resources) {
        if (context == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Context must not be null.");
        }

        if (resources == null) {
            return;
        }

        for (int resource : resources) {
            int soundId = sfx.load(context, resource, 1);
            sfxId.put(resource, soundId);
        }
    }

    public void play(int resId) {
        Integer soundId = sfxId.get(resId);
        if (soundId != null) {
            sfx.play(soundId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);
        }
    }

    public void release() {
        if (sfx != null) {
            sfx.autoPause();
            sfx.release();
            sfx = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo activity

```
package com.makeez.sfx;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SoundManager manager;
    private int position = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        manager = new SoundManager(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        manager.load(this, R.raw.sfx_0001, R.raw.sfx_0002, R.raw.sfx_0003, R.raw.sfx_0004, R.raw.sfx_0005);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0: manager.play(R.raw.sfx_0001); break;
                    case 1: manager.play(R.raw.sfx_0002); break;
                    case 2: manager.play(R.raw.sfx_0003); break;
                    case 3: manager.play(R.raw.sfx_0004); break;
                    case 4: manager.play(R.raw.sfx_0005); break;
                }

                if (++position >= 5) {
                    position = 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        manager.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```